# How to securely handout SSL Certifcate's truststore

Tags: java, ssl, https, truststore

I am developing a Java-based application that will run on a remote computer. This app will talk with a REST-API over the internet via HTTPS. I had this working using a truststore in P12 format. Is this the correct way to handout the SSL Cert? This program will be running on other users' computers. Will them having access to the P12 file be unsecure? If so, how could I go about this another way?

I am currently using the below for my client-software (that's on other peoples' computers):
`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", getFileFromResources("certs/newKeystore.p12").getAbsolutePath()); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password123");`
I know on my Rest-API server, it shouldn't be a problem because it's not accessible by anyone else. I am using the same P12 file on my rest-api server as well. If I change the P12 file, I should change it on both, correct?

Comment: The important thing is that you should not distribute the server’s private key to clients or anyone else. Having the private key allows you to impersonate the server. This means you need a separate trust store file that contains only the server’s public certificate, or preferably the public certificate of a certificate authority (CA) that has signed the server’s public certificate. If the server’s certificate or another certificate in the chain of trust can be signed by a well known CA that is already in the JDK’s default cacerts file, you don’t need to distribute anything.

Comment: A truststore doesn't actually need a password just to access it, and there is really nothing secure about it either: it just contains certificates, which are already public documents. What needs to be secure is the process of adding to it or removing from it, and that's where the password comes in. Each site should have its own password for its own truststore. Actually you shouldn't be exporting a truststore at all, just the certificates in it, with instructions as to how to import them once each user is satisfied as to the wisdom of trusting each one. Or get it signed as @TimMoore suggests.

Comment: @user207421+ not really. In the abstract security-theory world a truststore doesn't need confidentiality, but may still need a password for integrity. In particular most PKCS12 files by convention, including (in the Java-programming world) PKCS12 files created by Java keytool etc, use a password-MAC (which can be ignored in Java in some cases but not when using the sysprops shown) _and_ password-encrypt the certbag (even though it's not needed) and thus can only be used by providing the correct password.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 True, tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why a trust store exists is because you are trying to create a secure communication to a web server, and you need to trust the server certificate that they offer. So a trust store contains the trust anchors for that to happen: if a valid trust path can be build to a trust anchor in the trust store then the certificate is deemed valid and - after some additional checks of e.g. the server name - the private key can be used by the server to indicate that it is the server named within the server certificate.

Great, so what kind of security needs to be present on your trust store? Well, it is that the trust store is available and unaltered. Having the trust store unavailable will obviously be a big issue. So downloading the trust store every time you need to secure a connection is adding another high availability component to your infrastructure. Maybe you already need one for CRL or OCSP service, but still.

The other thing is that the trust store should not be altered in traffic. That basically means that the connection to your service should be free from attacks. The most logical way to do this is to have it protected by TLS. In that case of course you need a trusted certificate. In the end you cannot operate without trusting *something*. This is why you either have to trust a server based on the `cacerts`, or to distribute a certificate with the application.

"it shouldn't be a problem because it's not accessible by anyone else". That's not a requirement. Other people may well access the server, as long as they cannot alter the security (and availability) of the connection or the trust store. Read access to the P12 file wouldn't directly influence the availability or trustworthiness of the trust store. That said, the stricter the security of the service that contains the trust store, the better.

I was kind of afraid that the P12 would not just be a trust store but also a key store containing a private key. Preferably, a private key should not be distributed that way. I didn't see any hint of this happening in your question, so I'll just leave it here for other readers.

Comment: Right now the P12 file I believe contains my Cert and private key... which isn't good, right? I should try and make another P12 just using my Cert? Or can I make it using the Cert and Public Key? Then, just use the same P12 file on my Rest-Server. Is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: @Trent That is correct. It is terrible. It is beyond terrible. You are compromising your private key. This is the worst possible security breach. You need to export the certificate and distribute it. You don't need another truststore. Let the users do that part. This is very important from the legal non-repudiation point of view.

Comment: I got it figured out! I was trying to do a Server Certificate and a Client Certificate to authenticate, when in reality all I needed to do was a Server Cert, and have the client just use that Cert (like a browser does with a website). I was being too in-depth I think and not understanding what I was even doing. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, couldn't get back to you. In principle you always want to use local key pair generation + Certificate Signing Request for client authentication. Otherwise the key needs to be very well protected in transit, and of course the server would also have the private key. I'd keep the truststore with the trusted (root) certificates and the keystore with the cert chain for client authentication *separate* myself as they have different security requirements. PKI is an interesting subject for sure.